# Which one is more correct in this case? He or They?

Tags: grammar

What is more correct?

"A chef who's not an expert should never cook pufferfish, ______"

1.for he may be deadly poisoned if he does.

or

2.for they will be surely poisoned if they do.

I know that both "he" and "they" can be used when you don't know the gender of a person. But, if you have to choose between the two of these choices, which one will you choose?

I think #2 is more appropriate but "be surely poisoned" sounds weird to me. Like, the grammar sounds so weird

Which choice is more correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you’re asking about pronouns, why does the rest of the phrase change (“may...” vs “will...”)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who you ask; both 'he' and 'they' are technically correct, though 'he' sounds somewhat dated.

'Be surely poisoned' does sound a bit awkward - why have you changed the rest of the sentence if you are only asking about pronouns? If you use the same sentence as the first example but with 'they' instead of 'he', it would be 'for they may be deadly poisoned if they do', which sounds fine.

Comment: I want to ask about the rest of the sentence too, but I was too focused on the pronouns. Thanks!

Comment: _Will surely be poisoned_ is more idiomatic. It's up to you to decide whether you mean that they _may_ or _will_ be poisoned!